# NSOutlineView with manual Cocoa bindings

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller, nsoutlineview

I have an `NSOutlineView` that is bound to a `NSTreeController`. The details are like this:

- the treeController has class mode, and CommonListData as the Class Name, which has a "children" property
- the treeController also has "content array" bound to File's Owner's "headersArray" (of type `NSArray`). The "headersArray" is an array of CommonListData items
- the `NSOutlineView` has bindings for "Content" to the treeController's arrangedObjects
- the view-based outlineView is designed in Interface Builder, with each cell view has lots of elements. Each element (labels, images etc) have 'value' bindings to the `NSTableCellView` with the relevant objectValue.xxx model key paths

The setup is fairly simple, and it all works fine in adding and deleting objects. But the problem is that it doesn't use any of the `NSOutlineView` / `NSTableView` animations when adding or removing items from the outline view. The table just reloads itself if I add or remove any element to the treeController, or directly to the headersArray's children objects. I'm not sure if that is a limitation with Cocoa Bindings or what.

In any case, I am consider whether I can disable all the bindings and do this manually. The only drawback is that the `NSOutlineView` cell views have complicated elements on them, and I don't want to have to map the view elements to the data in code. Ideally it should keep the bindings in the `NSTableViewCell`.

**So my question is:**
Is it possible to keep the bindings within Interface Builder in a `NSTableCellView`, but not bind the content to the treeController? Or is there an alternative to binding "arrangedObjects", such that adding and removing data from the `NSTreeController` doesn't trigger an update to the UI?

It would help to have some more control over the bindings, so that I can trigger the animations correctly, and not have it just jump around with every update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the bindings of the views within the cell view are independent of the bindings of the outline view's content. Whether the outline view uses bindings or not, it eventually sets the `objectValue` property of the cell view. So long as that's done in a KVO-compliant manner (which it is), any bindings to that property will work.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure how to go about doing this. I removed the binding for the outlineView's content to the treeController's "arrangedObject". I implemented the required delegate methods: `outlineView: numberOfChildrenOfItem:` , `outlineView:child:ofItem:` , and `outlineView: viewForTableColumn:item:` and get the tableview to show all the rows correctly, but none of the labels in the tableviewCell that have bindings show up (the labels that are directly implemented in viewForTableColumn:item: are showing just fine). Any ideas? I'm guessing the `objectValue` isn't getting data?

Comment: Did you implement `-outlineView:objectValueForTableColumn:byItem:`?

Comment: No, that might be it! I'm a bit confused about what goes in `outlineView child:ofItem:` and `outlineView:objectValueForTableColumn:byItem` ... let me try to work this out and see if it works.